# Excel index/match formula issue

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have an issue with index/match formula in excel. I fill row A and B automatically (first name and last name) with index/match formula depending on a employee ID on C column which is dynamic (I pull it from another sheet and it refreshes/changes automatically)

When one or more employees are removed, my formula is messed up in some cells (A and B columns) related to column C.

Match($C sometimes becomes match(#REF! and sometimes it has wrong cell number, for example it has match($c5 instead of match($c6 because some employees are removed automatically)

Please see a picture and a hope everything will be much clearer.

Appreciate help.[image]

Comment: You would be better to put `=index('employee list'!b:b, match($c5, 'employee list'!$a:$a, 0))` in A5 as a standard, non-array, non-cse formula then drag it to B5 then drag A5:B5 down.

Comment: ... or maybe `=iferror(index('employee list'!b:b, match($c5, 'employee list'!$a:$a, 0)), text(,))`

Comment: Jeeped,
I don't see any problem using array formula here but $c is incorrect after  some employees are removed as I described.

Comment: then it's unclear what you are trying to do. do you want a:b to skip the missing ids in c or do you need help refreshing c so the missing ids are no longer listed?

Comment: I want C to somehow recalculated/refreshed so formula is aware that some rows are deleted

Comment: As you can see in my picture (right side), instead of #REF!, there should be Liz Lukic.

Comment: you've only provided information on a:b, not c. and my crystal ball is in the shop for an overdue maintenance overhaul.

Comment: As you can see in a formula, A and B are populated depending on value in C column (employee ID).

Comment: as you seem to be unwilling to try my full column reference solution to receiving #REF! after deleting rows, i'll just suggest converting your employee list ranges to index pairs with hardcoded/dynamic row references and move on.

Comment: I tried your first solution and had the same issue. Tried the second and got the similar issue. #ref! instead of correct $C value). My correction in question. No rows are removed but cells in C,D,E rows). I just realized that.

Comment: had u tried to enter the formula without pressing CSE (ctrl + shift + Enter)?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the source data into a true table with structured references (Ctrl + T) that may get rid of your REF errors when the source changes.